# Calculate minutes from a certain time to current time c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a certain time ie. 10.30 AM. The user makes entry in a table. If the user makes entry after 10.30 AM , then the number of minutes from 10.30 Am to the current time should be calculated and set to a string.

Here is what I tried uptil now:-

```
int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
int mins = DateTIme.Now.Minute
if(hour>10 && mins >30)
{
    string lateBy = "You are late by:"+ //????? how do I calculate this?
}
```

Any help would be great

Comment: `(certain_time - Date.Now).TotalMinutes` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `TimeSpan` to find the difference between the 2 datetime values, and use the `TotalMinutes` property to get the difference in minutes.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime start = new DateTime(today.Year,today.Month,today.Day,10,30,00);
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
int hour = now.Hour;
int mins = now.Minute;

TimeSpan ts = now.Subtract(start);
if(ts.TotalMinutes > 0) //Time now is after 10:30
 {  
  string lateBy = "You are late by:"+ ts.TotalMinutes.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: i tried your solution, but I get the minutes in negative

Comment: Try `now - start`. Not sure why you are getting thia reault though.

Comment: the condition `if(hour>10 && mins >30)` goes false if the time is lets say 11.25. Thats the reason I get negative values. How do I solve it?

Comment: Can you check what is the time you are getting for `now`? That being less than 10:30 AM would explain the negative. I have also updated my code to handle the `hour` and `mins` comparison issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring dates and assuming it is always the same day as the 10:30 deadline day:

```
string lateBy = "You are late by:"+ ((hour-10)*60 + mins-30) + " minutes";
```

Note this only works before midnight, i.e. for the same day.

Comment: using **TimeSpan** is a better answer than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Since both are DateTime, you can make use of [`DateTime.Subract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.subtract.aspx)

```
DateTime a = new DateTime(2014, 06, 20, 10, 30, 00);
DateTime b = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("You  are late by:"+b.Subtract(a).TotalMinutes +"minutes");
Console.ReadLine();
```